# Spring Security entry point

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

The problem is that the user is getting logged in with the context "/oauth/token" but I am unable to find the exact entry point. There is no controller or anything written.How is it working? How is the spring security getting call and process the requests? My spring boot project version is 2.2.1.RELEASE and java version 1.8

I tried making some basic project and cannot get a hand on it.I which class or files do I have to look and any documentation or blogs that will help me please provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Security's servlet support is based on servlet filters.

The entry point for Spring Security is the `FilterChainProxy` which invokes one `SecurityFilterChain` with multiple filters configured.

Placing a breakpoint in `FilterChainProxy#doFilter` can help you understand what happens.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/servlet/architecture.html#servlet-filters-review